# Element disappears again immediately after fadeIn ()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

http://robinj.be/unity-2d-config-util/

In the source code there's this:

```
<div class="dash page" id="home">
    <?php include ('pages/home.php'); ?>
</div>
<div class="dash page" id="screenshots">
    <?php include ('pages/screenshots.php'); ?>
</div>
```

But when opening the page, Firebug only shows the `div.cash.page#home` part.

When you click the camera icon at the bottom of the page, what should happen is this:

1. The current page disappears.
2. A page with screenshots fades in.

But what happens is this:

1. The current page disappears.
2. The page with screenshots fades in.
3. The page with screenshots disappears.

What could be the problem in this situation?

--Edit--
For the *Recent revisions* block, I download a page from [Launchpad](http://launchpad.net), which I then filter by using a *Regular Expression*. Apparently, though, my regex takes a bit too much HTML with it :/

Comment: The screenshots appear for me, but below the bottom bar. Maybe you should move the div up in the DOM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my Chrome they are loaded behind your background. When adding position: relative; to the wrapper div (dash page) they appear on top.

Comment: That makes the images appear for me too, although I had to do this for the yui-g class instead.. Just one note: my resolution causes the images to appear on two lines. Because the screenshots div is now on top, I can no longer hit the "Home" button to get out of there.

Comment: @abelito I think they are just not styled yet?

Comment: A faulty regex was the problem >.<

Answer (score 1):

This may not apply to the specific scenario here, but I came upon this page when encountering a similar issue with HTML/jQuery and realized later that the issue stemmed from forgetting to add event.preventDefault(); to the event handler, in case that is helpful to those troubleshooting this issue in the future.